# Looking for a REST-based remote filesystem

Tags: rest, filesystems, storage

This is a very open/general question (I hope not too general anyway:))

I'm looking for a library/module that could be plugged in a web server (like apache) and handle REST requests to store / retrieve / delete files.
Something like Amazon's S3 or Windows Azure storage, but open-sourced.

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: FTP was not an option for you? On top of it I crafted (in Prolog) my duties to handle some site...

Comment: FTP is the protocol being currently used. And I have a lot of good reasons for replacing it :)

Answer (score 4):

[mod_dav](http://www.webdav.org/mod_dav/)? DAV is the original generic/bare-bones REST. You PUT files, then you can GET them back or DELETE them... But that doesn't provide any management by itself, and maybe that is that you are looking for. Have you looked into [OpenStack](http://www.openstack.org/), specifically the object storage component?

Comment: Thanks, however WebDAV was a bit complicated for me. I thought until today that REST ancestor was SOAP, and SOAP is deprecated for the same complexity reasons. On the other hand, OpenStack seems interesting.

Comment: If you find WebDAV complicated then I must warn you that you will find OpenStack to be a nightmare. REST is conceptually simple: there are objects, they are addressed by URIs, and you can read them (GET) and write them (PUT).

Answer (score 4):

There is OpenStack SWIFT which is open source clone of the Amazon's s3. It is lineary scalable and provides REST interface to the data. http://swift.openstack.org/

Answer (score 2):

I solved a similar problem using [Node-FSAPI](https://github.com/Fluidbyte/Node-FSAPI), a NodeJS-based server that exposes a selected part of the file system as a REST api. (It's not an Apache module like you asked for, but it solves the same problem.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a distributed file system at the same time? If so I suggest using Apache Hadoop's [HDFS](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HDFS) and the [WebHDFS REST API](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html) to access the file system.

How ever I am not sure whether this can be deployed as an extension to Apache or any other web server :-( Just wanted to share this idea, if you are looking for a distributed file system with guaranteed reliability etc.

Comment: I didn't write much details, because I'm in early research phase. But regarding replication, I would like to be able to do real-time or scheduled replication (for example, synchronize servers at night only). Because I don't think an existing solution totally fits my needs, I'm looking for an open source one.
However the solution seems interesting.

Comment: The links in this answer give a 404